# How to setup Hive with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hi how I can setup hive that is using mysql with hadoop. Can anyone help me with step by instruction. I have done some reaches for hive on hadoop but didn't succeeded with because it uses derby

Comment: Check this link for how to change hive meta store from derby to mysql http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-configure-mysql-metastore

Comment: Hi @RajenRaiyarela .. I followed all the steps in that link and still facing issues. 
I am trying to configure mysql with hive from a very very long time, Everytime I encounter errors I don't understand where I am going wrong ..... as you can see in this link gist.github.com/anonymous/bb86629116891e5b2d8c30b95aca9aee hive-site.xml configuration can be seen here in the link gist.github.com/anonymous/44f1c9fc214136a113067cf3b4b72794 Here is file-structure gist.github.com/anonymous/e02b3631da940dfae880252ca72107de

Comment: @KJ_kaka pl create your new question with all the details along with error your are getting. Currently without knowing your error it is difficult to know what is the issue. Specify your Hive version too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545207/unable-to-start-hive-metastore-service-or-hive-shell-after-configuring-mysql-wit?noredirect=1#comment60697449_36545207